# SQL cases printing XML to a single line. Need multiple lines

Tags: sql, xml, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a SELECT query using SQLDeveloper that uses many cases to pull results for application numbers. However, a single application number can fall into multiple cases. We are generating an XML file where we need each case to be a new line. The query is just bundling all the information into a single line.

**Here is the query:**

```
select XMLElement("wo-national-office-event",
XMLAttributes('US' as "office-code",
tbl3.PERCENT_NUMBER as "international-application",
trim(tbl3.DN_Another_Identifier) as "national-application",

CASE WHEN TBL_1.FILE_DATE between to_date('2/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY') and to_date('3/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY') THEN 'E' END as "event-type",
CASE WHEN ISSUE_DATE between to_date('2/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY') and to_date('3/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY') THEN 'G' END as "event-type",
CASE WHEN TBL_2.PUBLICATION_DATE  between to_date('2/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY') and to_date('3/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY') THEN 'P' END as "event-type", 

CASE WHEN TBL_1.FILE_DATE between to_date('2/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY') and to_date('3/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY') THEN to_char(TBL_1.FILE_DATE, 'yyyymmdd') END as "event-date",
CASE WHEN ISSUE_DATE between to_date('2/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY') and to_date('3/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY') THEN to_char(ISSUE_DATE, 'yyyymmdd' END) as "event-date",
CASE WHEN TBL_2.PUBLICATION_DATE  between to_date('2/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY') and to_date('3/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY') THEN TO_char(TBL_2.PUBLICATION_DATE, 'yyyymmdd' END) as "event-date",
CASE WHEN ISSUE_DATE between to_date('2/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY') and to_date('3/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY') THEN patent_no END) as "publication-number",
CASE WHEN TBL_2.PUBLICATION_DATE  between to_date('2/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY') and to_date('3/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY') THEN TBL_2.PUBLICATION_YEAR || TBL_2.PUBLICATION_NUMBER END as "publication-number",
CASE WHEN TBL_2.PUBLICATION_DATE  between to_date('2/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY') and to_date('3/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY') THEN TBL_2.PUBLICATION_CODE END as "publication-code"
)
) as RESULT
from 
TBL_1, TBL_2, TBL_3 tbl3 where
TBL_1.Some_Identifier = tbl3.Dn_Another_Identifier  
and SOME_INDICATOR = 'Y'
and Some_Identifier like '15%'
and TBL_1.FKEY_ID = TBL_2.FKEY_ID
and (TBL_1.FILE_DATE between to_date('2/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY') and to_date('3/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')
or ISSUE_DATE between to_date('2/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY') and to_date('3/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')
or TBL_2.PUBLICATION_DATE  between to_date('2/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY') and to_date('3/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));
```

**Here are the results:**

```
Query Order: A B C D X1 Y1 X2 Y2 X3 Y3 X4 Y4 E

<wo-national-office-event office-code="US" international-application="AAA/111/AAA" national-application="12345" event-type="G" event-type="P" event-date="20190226" event-date="20190214" publication-number="654321" publication-number="123456" publication-code="B12"/>
```

**The results I'm trying to achieve:**

```
Query order:
A B C D X1 X2 X3 X4
A B C D Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4 E

<wo-national-office-event office-code="US" international-application="AAA/111/AAA" national-application="12345" event-type="G" event-date="20190226" publication-number="654321"/>
<wo-national-office-event office-code="US" international-application="AAA/111/AAA" national-application="12345" event-type="P" event-date="20190214" publication-number="123456" publication-code="B12"/>
```

I was looking at the PIVOT command but I need the record to print multiple times while retaining it's XML formatting.

Comment: Please tag the database engine you’re using. This isn’t anything standard SQL does.

Comment: Done. Sorry about that.